# How would i getX() from a rectangle in a shape array list

Tags: java, shapes

Okay so I have a shape arraylist containing a rectangle. How would i obtain the x coordinate of that rectangle from the arraylist?

I think i didn't make it clear so here it is: 
So here is the arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>() ;
```

Creating the shape:

```
Shape rec1 = new Rectangle(100,100,200,200);
shapes.add(rec1);
```

now how can i get the x coordinate? I tried:

```
Shape j = (Shape)shapes.get(i);
j.getX()
```

But that didn't work.. error: cannot find symbol

Comment: How do you **get** elements from an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Which one?  I assume you have a number of them in the `ArrayList`.  Perhaps you should have a look at the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: You may need to cast your shape to `Rectangle`, if your list is an `ArrayList<Shape>`.

Comment: @DavidWallace You could simply use `Shape#getBounds` which would return the rectangular bounds of the given shape, in this case, possibly `Rectangle` bounds itself

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to avoid making any assumptions about what the `Shape` and `Rectangle` classes are.  These could well be the OP's own classes.

Comment: Sorry guys updated OP

Comment: Define "didn't work" please. What happens? Error message? Show it. Exception? Show it. Toaster blows up? Describe it. Also, why not use a generic `ArrayList<Rectangle>`?

Comment: Error: Cannot find symbol and it points at j.getX()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape does not necessarily have a single x coordinate. So you could change your ArrayList so its type is Rectangle:

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> shapes = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
```

Or you can get the bounds with [getBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#getBounds%28%29):

```
Shape s = shapes.get(i);
double x = s.getBounds().getX();
```

For a Rectangle this basically creates a copy of itself but if you have to include other shapes you don't really have a choice (except some kind of case-by-case casting).

Comment: Dude, getBounds() was exactly what i was looking for thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3250769 You're welcome. In the future, the API docs are very useful for this kind of thing. ; )

Answer (score 1):

Cast the object to a `Rectangle`, not a `Shape` (`getX()` is defined in class `Rectangle`, not in `Shape`):

```
Rectangle r = (Rectangle) shapes.get(i);
r.getX();
```

However this is not probably what you want: if you have a list of `Shape`s, not all of them will be `Rectangle`s. You can check whether the object is a `Rectangle` or not before using it:

```
Shape j = (Shape) shapes.get(i);
if (j instanceof Rectangle) {
    ((Rectangle) j).getX();
}
```